# Ubuntu server extend root disk

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I want to extend my root volume but I think I'm missing a crucial step.

In the `/etc/fstab` file I found following entries:

[image]

After `lvdisplay` I get following results:

[image]

So it looks like the LV size is 40.00GiB

As final check I entered the following command: `df -h`

[image]

Where is the remaining disk space?

Just to clear a few things out: I'm not a server guy, but a software engineer. The guy who created the servers(templates) said it would be easy to extend the disks. He already tried a few hours to do this, but wasn't able to complete the task. So, could someone help me to solve this issue (or give an appropriate solution)?

Comment: Please use  use cut-and-paste for posting console output and [format](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) it as "`code`" or "`<pre>`" rather than posting screenshots. That often improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I had to extend memory on an ubuntu device (14.04) I used the command `lvdisplay`, `lvextend` and `resize2fs`.

using `sudo lvdisplay`, note the LV Path and the Free PE/Size (should be a plain number).

after that, I used `sudo lvextend -l <Free PE/Size> <LV Path>`.

lastly the command `sudo resize2fs <LV Path>` did the actual resizing.

I checked to see if it was done with `Df -h`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot the `resize2fs` command! Now it works :)